# How to save the output of "kubectl get events --all-namespaces" command on every hourly basis or on daily basis?

Tags: kubernetes, events, azure-aks, filebeat, graylog

I have 3 kubernetes cluster and i am trying to save the output of "kubectl get events --all-namespaces" on hourly/daily basis.

Current setup:

1. 3 Azure kubernetes clusters.
2. Using "filebeat" to ship the logs.
3. Shipping the logs to "Graylog"

Currently fetching the container logs on the path `:/var/lib/docker/containers`

Please help me in finding a way to ship the output of "kubectl get events --all-namespaces" AND events logs on cluster level.

Comment: What are "event logs" if not the output of `kubectl get events`? Do you mean container logs?

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a [K8s Cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)  with a docker image with kubectl installed and runs "kubectl get events -A" as shown in the Dockerfile below
2. Create a service account, clusterrole, clusterrolebinding, that gives "get events" permissions to the service account
3. Use this service account in the cronjob manifest
4. When the job runs as scheduled, the logs of the kubectl get events will be sent to the container logs
5. Filebeat will do the rest

Details on configuring a pod to run kubectl are here:

https://itnext.io/running-kubectl-commands-from-within-a-pod-b303e8176088

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:buster
RUN apt update && \
      apt install -y curl && \
      curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl && \
      chmod +x ./kubectl && \
      mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
CMD kubectl get events -A
```